# Creation of URLSession freezing the app in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, urlsession

I am creating a `URLSession` for a background download task as follows,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, URLSessionDelegate {
    var session: URLSession!
    lazy var downloadsSession: URLSession = {
      let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier:
        "bgDownloader")
//        configuration.sessionSendsLaunchEvents = true
        let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
      return session
    } ()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("started")
        session = downloadsSession
        print("done")
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

Whenever the control hits the `let session = URLSession(...)` line in viewdidload() the app freezes. Any help?

Comment: Can you please share the code where you invoke this URLSession?

Comment: First, are you sure you don’t have any [breakpoints](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/11.4/index.html?localePath=en.lproj#/dev1cf0a324f) in your code? Second, put this in a blank project and you’ll see that this code is insufficient to cause it to freeze. The problem rests elsewhere.

Comment: @Rob I created a blank project and tried it. It's still freezing. Updated the original post to include the whole code.

Comment: Try running on the main thread? DispatchQueue.main.async {
//code
}

Comment: @purebreadd It didn't help. Even after putting lazy creation of urlsession inside main.aync it stucks

Comment: The dispatch to the main queue is unnecessary (and `async` only introduces unnecessary race conditions). The `static let` instantiates lazily in a thread-safe manner. That having been said, if it’s freezing as you describe, there’s still something else going on, because many of us use this pattern without incident. Perhaps you can upload your sample blank project somewhere and we can take a look at it for you.

Comment: @Rob I have uploaded the sample blank project  to https://bitbucket.org/gouthamvgk/test/src/master/  .Thank you so much for your comments and help. I am using XCODE 11.4 and iphone 11 pro max simulator

Comment: Thank you. The problem still exists. Anyway for now i solved by using a default urlsession until i update my xcode or get to try in different machines. You mentioned that urlsession shouldn't be a property of viewcontroller. Is there any explicit reason?? Can you point to any threads about it?? @Rob

Comment: First, there’s just the general high-level concept that view controllers are for populating views and for responding to user interactions. Business logic, network code for making requests, parsing responses, etc., really don’t belong there, in the spirit of the [“single responsibility principle”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle). See links in this answer for thoughts about architectural patterns: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60423674/1271826

Comment: But, the concerns about burying the `URLSession` code in the view controller is even more critical with background sessions. When your next view controller needs to do some requests, are you going to create another `URLSession` for that view controller with the same identifier. That’s not going to work. With background sessions, you want one session per identifier, and while you could theoretically put it in the view controller (say, your app has only one view controller), but it’s quickly going to become a mess in more complicated scenarios.

Comment: @Rob it seems that the problem is with XCODE. Once I updated to the latest version background downloader works like a charm. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s something going on because this code, alone is not sufficient to manifest the problem. E.g. I ran your project and see both `print` statements:

[image]

This is in Xcode 11.4.1 (11E503a) and iPhone 11 Pro Max simulator running on macOS Catalina 10.15.4 (19E287), though I’ve used this sort of pattern for many different Xcode versions, without incident.

If you’re getting weird behavior, you can:

- Reset the simulator: Choosing “Device” » “Erase All Content and Settings...” » “Erase”.
- Empty Derived Data: When getting inexplicable behaviors, it’s prudent to empty the Derived Data folder (“Xcode” » “Preferences...” » “Locations”, tap on the arrow next to the derived data path; quit Xcode; delete everything in the Derived Data folder; and restart Xcode). I can’t imagine that this will help, but is a good first step whenever you get incorrect/inexplicable behaviors.
- Reboot and/or try other computer: If you’re really still seeing this behavior, reboot your machine, try it on another person’s computer, etc. But there’s nothing wrong with the instantiation of the background session.

(Needless to say, longer term, this download session shouldn’t be a property of the view controller, but that’s a bigger picture issue you can tackle once you’ve got your immediate problem behind you.)